# Is it safe to cast an Object to a primitive type if you know it is of the associated wrapper class's type AND not null?

Tags: java, casting, runtime-error, wrapper

There are two cases I'm curious about, which I'm not sure is different in any way that would affect the answer. Regardless, in these two cases, is this casting always safe?

### case 1:

```
Object obj = ???; // unknown value for obj
boolean b;

if (obj != null && obj instanceof Boolean) 
    b = (boolean) obj;
```

### case 2:

```
Object obj = ???;
float f;

if (obj != null && obj.getClass().equals(Float.class))
    f = (float) obj;
```

Comment: Looks safe to me. Is there a problem that you are having with this code, that makes you suspect that this is not safe?

Comment: The first seems fine, but the second case might worry me as the .equals() method only uses the instance loaded by the classloader, so I don't know if this could vary and return false if it should be true

Comment: Well yes you are right in that part. But this has nothing to do with safety, right? if `equals` returns `false`, the cast won't run anyway.

Comment: oh, does .equals() span that gap, if two classloaders are involved?